# How to count records in a fifteen minute time interval while grouping by distinct record

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm attempting to count the number of records within a 15 minute time interval from a timestamp field. I essentially want to count the number of fifteen minute time intervals per USER_ID. I'm new to teradata so I'm probably not utilizing it's full potential here, but was looking for any sort of guidance.

> Current Table Data

[image: Current Table Data]

> Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

### Current SQL that is failing

```
SELECT
 user_id,
 CAST(CREATION_DATE as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') as contact_date,
 CAST(CREATION_DATE as TIME) contact_time, 
 HOUR(contact_time) AS h, 
 MINUTE(contact_time)-(MINUTE(contact_time) MOD 15) AS m, 
 COUNT(*) contact_count
FROM 
table1
```

Comment: How exactly do you define *15 minute interval*?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more slick way of solving this with some of the new temporal logic introduced in like 16.10(I think), but this will do the job:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(creation_period)
FROM
(
   SELECT NORMALIZE
      user_id,
       CASE 
         WHEN PERIOD(creation_date, NEXT(creation_date + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)) CONTAINS LEAD(creation_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY creation_date)
            THEN PERIOD(creation_date, NEXT(LEAD(creation_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY creation_date)))
         WHEN PERIOD(creation_date - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE, NEXT(CREATION_DATE)) CONTAINS LAG(creation_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY creation_date)
            THEN PERIOD(LAG(creation_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY creation_date), NEXT(creation_date))
         ELSE
            PERIOD(creation_date, NEXT(creation_date))
         END AS creation_period
   FROM table1
) dt
GROUP BY 1;
```

Basically what this is doing is stitching together a `Period` data type by looking for neighboring records that are in that 15 minute interval. We then `Normalize` records for each distinct `user_id` where those manufactured periods intersect or overlap each other. Then we just count distinct periods that remain.

Input:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE table1
(
   user_id VARCHAR(30),
   creation_date TIMESTAMP(0)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0));
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '1' DAY);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '2' DAY);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '3' DAY);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '3' DAY + INTERVAL '3' MINUTE);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user' || '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0));
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user' || '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user' || '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '11' MINUTE);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user' || '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user' || '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '20' MINUTE);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user' || '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '3' MINUTE);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('user' || '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) + INTERVAL '3' DAY + INTERVAL '3' MINUTE);
```

Output:

```
+---------+------------------------+
| user_id | Count(creation_period) |
+---------+------------------------+
| user    |                      4 |
| user2   |                      3 |
+---------+------------------------+
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Was not aware of the PERIOD datatype. Thanks so much.

Comment: Your logic is way too complicated, `PERIOD(creation_date, NEXT(creation_date+ INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)) AS creation_period` should work the same :-)

Comment: @dnoeth That was like my 3rd iteration over a 5 minute period and I totally backed into this solution and of course you are correct. LOLOLOL!